# The TEXT Function in Excel: Date to another date format

Tags: excel

In previous Excel version, we have dates such as 01.01.2012 that we automatically converted to this format using:
 =TEXT(C1;"yyyy-mm") to get : 2012-01
If I open the document in Excel 2013, I get this: yyyy-00. 
Does anyone know where the error lies.  I have tried many different solutions to fix it , but cannot find it!

Thank you for any help:)

Comment: what regional setting do you use (Control Panel->Clock, Language, and Region -> Region Settings)?

Answer (score 0):

In some languages **mm** gives minutes but **MM** gives months, and you need **yyyy** to change too, so in German you would need this:

`=TEXT(C1;"jjjj-MM")`

Once you work out which format works in `TEXT` function I'd suggest that you use cell formatting rather than `TEXT` function, e.g. if you use just =C1 and then custom format with "jjjj-MM", or whatever works, then in future that will automatically update if regional settings are changed - `TEXT` function won't update